# browser window size in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

We're trying to capture a report of actual browser window size in Google Analytics. I know they've got their in-page analytics, but that doesn't provide data, just a visualization. Anyone know if we're missing something or if we need to add this as a custom event?

Is this really necessary?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var width  = window.innerWidth  || document.body.clientWidth;
 var height = window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

 width  = Math.round(width/100)*100;
 height = Math.round(height/100)*100;

 var size = width + "x" + height;
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Browser Size', 'Range', size]);
</script>
```

Comment: I think this would make more sense as a custom variable rather than event. It's more of an attribute of your users than an event that happens.

Comment: Now, GA has "Browser size" which does this.
Definition: Visible browser viewport size.

Answer (score 6):

You do need to add a custom event. I tried the javascript you had, but it messed with Google Analytic's Bounce Rate. You need to pass the opt_noninteraction variable as "true", otherwise Google considers the event a user interaction. Tracking the browser window size is not a user interaction and should be excluded from the bounce rate calc.

Here is the modified code:

```
<script>
var width = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
width  = Math.round(width/10)*10;
height = Math.round(height/10)*10; //Using a 10 pixel granularity

var size = width + "x" + height;
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Browser Size', 'Range', size,, true]); //don't count in Bounce Rate
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

For future viewers of this question: A "Browser size" dimension is available in google analytics at least since 2012 (as mentioned in [this article](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2012/06/new-feature-conduct-browser-size.html), thanks Stephen Ostermiller).

[image: Screenshot from google analytics with Browser size]

Comment: It appears that Google made "Browser Size" available as a dimension in June 2012: https://analytics.googleblog.com/2012/06/new-feature-conduct-browser-size.html

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use the [Screen Resolution Report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1144432?hl=en) under Audience > Technology > Browser & OS, right?

[image: Browser & OS - Google Analytics]

Comment: This was my thought too, but with the Javascript variables that would lead me to believe he wants to track browser window size, not screen resolution.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought but thought I would throw it out there. The js looks fine. Are you having issues?

Comment: we haven't tried the JS at all, really wanted to see if anyone knew anything inside of existing GA that already produced this.

Comment: I'm only aware of the Screen Resolution Report to get screen sizes. You'll have to use that js to get the granularity you want.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find this for the longest time.